# If $p, q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and both $A$ and $B$ don't separate $p$ and $q$, then neither does $A\cup B$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am stuck in the exercises of Ib Madsen and Jorgen Tornehave's *From Calculus to Cohomology*.

> (Phragmen-Brouwer property of $\mathbb{R}^n$) Suppose $p\neq q$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. A closed set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to separate $p$ from $q$, when $p$ and $q$ belong to two different connected components of $\mathbb{R}^n - A$.
>
> Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given two distinct points $p$ and $q$ in $\mathbb{R}^n - (A\cup B)$. Show that if neither $A$ nor $B$ separates $p$ from $q$, then $A\cup B$ does not separate $p$ from $q$. (Apply Theorem $5.2$ to $U_1 = \mathbb{R}^n - A$, $U_2 = \mathbb{R}^n - B$.)

The hint given is to apply Mayer-Vietoris sequence to $\mathbb R^n-A$ and $\mathbb R^n-B$. I arrived to this:

$$0\to\mathbb R\to H^0(\mathbb R^n-A)\oplus H^0(\mathbb R^n-B)\to H^0(\mathbb R^n-A\cup B)\to 0$$

I am not sure how to proceed. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider the maps used in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Using the $U_1$ and $U_2$ as suggested in the question, we have

$$0 \to H^0(\mathbb{R}^n) \xrightarrow{k^*\oplus\ l^*} H^0(U_1)\oplus H^0(U_2) \xrightarrow{i^*-j^*} H^0(U_1\cap U_2) \to 0$$

where

\begin{align*}
i &: U_1\cap U_2 \to U_1\\
j &: U_1\cap U_2 \to U_2\\
k &: U_1 \to \mathbb{R}^n\\
l &: U_2 \to \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}

are all inclusion maps.

I'm assuming you're using de Rham cohomology. In that case, $H^0(X)$ is the vector space of locally constant real-valued functions on $X$. Note, $x_0, x_1 \in X$ are in the same connected component if and only if $f(x_0) = f(x_1)$ for every $f \in H^0(X)$. If $r : Y \to X$ is an inclusion map, then the induced map $r^* : H^0(X) \to H^0(Y)$ is given by $r^*(f) = f\circ r = f|_Y$.

Let $h \in H^0(U_1\cap U_2)$. By the exactness of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, there is $f \in H^0(U_1)$ and $g \in H^0(U_2)$ such that $(i^*-j^*)(f, g) = h$. As $p$ and $q$ are in the same connected component of $U_1$, $f(p) = f(q)$; likewise, as $p$ and $q$ are in the same connected component of $U_2$, $g(p) = g(q)$. Expanding out the definitions, we see that $h = f|_{U_1\cap U_2} - g|_{U_1\cap U_2}$. Then

\begin{align*}
h(p) &= f|_{U_1\cap U_2}(p) - g|_{U_1\cap U_2}(p)\\ 
&= f(p) - g(p)\\ 
&= f(q) - g(q)\\ 
&= f|_{U_1\cap U_2}(q) - g|_{U_1\cap U_2}(q)\\ 
&= h(q).
\end{align*}

Therefore, $p$ and $q$ must belong to the same connected component of $U_1\cap U_2 = \mathbb{R}^n\setminus(A\cup B)$. That is, $A\cup B$ does not separate $p$ and $q$.